# how to give a style for a variable which is get as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i got my id in a variable now i want to give style for it i use code like

```js
 var x = parseInt($("tr.selected").attr('data-id'));

$("#"+x+"").css("left", startvalue );
```

but this is not good one please give me any method
here x is a variable which is a selected tr data-id .i use the same name for my div id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't worry  i got the answer

```js
  $("#"+x).css("left", startvalue );
```

there some "" problem

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code like this:

1) Use `.data()` to get data attribute value.

2) Use radix in `parseInt` method

3) you don't need extra empty string at the end while creating jquery object:

```
var x = parseInt($("tr.selected").data('id'),10);
                                  ^^1       ^^2
$("#"+x).css("left", startvalue );
       ^^3
```

Comment: `data()` souldn't be used, because if for some reason there is actual data band to that element, then jQuery will return the data rather than the data attribute. Also, there is no need for `parseInt` at all, because he is converting back to string when appending to '#'.

Comment: @metal03326: OP is using the same variable somewhere else